# Powershell unexpected behavior of uncaught exception inside a catch block

Tags: powershell, uncaught-exception, catch-block

The following powershell script produce a very unexcepted output:

```
try {
    throw "some exception"
    echo "check point"
}
catch
{
    echo "catch"
    throw "some other exception"
    exit(-1)
}
echo "finish"
```

output:

```
catch
finish
```

I would except the script to exit either by the uncaught exception `throw "some exception"` and for the script not reach `finish`.

Even if Powershell is set to continue after uncaught exception, I would expect it to execute `exit(-1)` and never reach `finish`.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: How are you running this? I am unable to replicate your results.

Comment: Is `$ErrorActionPreference` set to SilentlyContinue?

Comment: The code is in a script file `test.ps1` and running the script file from the shell.

Comment: I believe `$ErrorActionPreference` default value is `Continue`

Answer (score 1):

`exit(-1)` is unreachable because the previous line, `throw "some other exception"`, throws an exception which bypasses the rest of the block.

I see "finish" being reached in two cases:

- As Bacon Bits said, when `$ErrorActionPreference` is set to `"SilentlyContinue"`.
- The code is pasted into the interactive shell (as opposed to run from a .ps1 file), in which case it runs the final line as a manual command.

Comment: I would expect `throw "some other exception"` will exit from the script file back to the shell and not just to exit the catch block.

Comment: That's the part about "finish" in my answer.